# Recent commands searchable in history but not listed after power outage

Tags: r

I'd been working on a project in RStudio all day when the power went out across half of San Francisco... Once power came back it appeared my commands that weren't from a saved workspace were not longer listed in my command history. HOWEVER those commands are actually searchable (and therefore living somewhere on my machine). I need to save this hidden history to a file so I can run all the commands again. Anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** In contrary to `R`, `RStudio` saves all history commands in `history_database` file, so that history can be retrieved after unexpected `RStudio` crashes due to power loss, etc..

The `history_database` file is located in

**On Windows:** `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop`

**On Mac | Nix:** `~/RStudio-Desktop`

`history_database` file is a normal ASCII text file and it can be viewed by any text editor.

If you can search history in the current workspace, then save all those history commands in a file:

```
savehistory(file = "myhist.Rhistory")
```

Then load it whenever necessary

```
loadhistory(file = "myhist.Rhistory")
```

To find out the location of history file in the current workspace

```
getwd()
dir(all.files = TRUE)
```

Look for `".Rhistory"` hidden file. This file contains all history commands.

For more info: `?"history"`

If you want to set the default location of the `.Rhistory` file in your environment,

Get the current value:

```
options("R_HISTFILE")
```

Set the R_HISTFILE to a desired location:

```
options(R_HISTFILE = "file_path")
```

For more info: `?options`

Comment: Unfortunately the hidden .Rhistory file only seems to contain the same thing that outputs from RStudio's listed history, not the commands I lost (but are still searchable).

Comment: Meaning I can search for code committed prior to losing power in RStudio (in the top right search window) but it isn't listed in the actual window of command history otherwise. When I export my history or dig into the hidden .RHistory file as you've suggested that "searchable" code is also not there – but it must be somewhere if I can search for it!

Comment: Correct – yet I can search for it and even see it in context. I just need to be able to export all of that to a file so I can rerun it.

Comment: It's okay – when I export the history the only code I can see is from my last save (not the code from before power loss). When I view history I see the same thing. Yet strangely when I actively search for  unsaved code I had committed using the search field, my unsaved code is retrievable. Looks like the same problem described here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202694927-After-terminated-R-session-history-is-not-saved

Comment: R_HISTFILE is set to .RHistory, but that file shows only the saved code, just as in the history window of RStudio.

Comment: I'm back in the original project. And no, using Mac.

Comment: Is perfect, I don't believe this specific issue has been answered elsewhere on Stack Exchange yet.